# How to use date and time received in a outlook mail in a event calender of outlook?

Tags: email, events, calendar, outlook, registration

Like Google calender, is it possible to make a functionality such that when some one register an event from website with date and time, then event will be added in an outlook event calender automatically.

I have found a solution with .ics file, but it does not work. It trigger an error that 'the file is not valid internet calender file'.

Please help with some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an add-in which can parse the incoming emails and do the required actions if required. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

If you deal only with Exchange profiles in Outlook you may consider using EWS. Read more about that in the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) article in MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
I will go through this link and come back if any question..
please help me out if i am in trouble in future :)